# Scrapy. I get key error ( last_page) when passing value through meta in request. It works once but gives keyerror when looping for pagination

Tags: python, scrapy, keyerror

I am new to Scrapy and I get a key error when passing last_page through meta in the request.

```
 def parse_start(self, response):
        
        last_page = response.request.meta['last_page']

        dress_links = response.xpath('//p[@class="brand"]/a/@href').getall()
        for dress_link in dress_links:
            link_item = 'https://www.modanisa.com/en' + dress_link
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = link_item, 
                callback=self.parse_clothing, 
                meta={'link_item' : link_item})
        
        for idx_next in range(2, last_page+1):
            url_next = 'https://www.modanisa.com/en/dresses-en.list' + f'?page={idx_next}'
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = url_next,
                callback = self.parse_start
            )
```

And this is the error I get:

> last_page = response.meta['last_page']
> KeyError: 'last_page'

Is there a way to keep the value of last_page constant throughout the scraping?

Comment: You should represent full code here so that  everyone can test it and point out the solution

Comment: Is last_page defined?